# How to customize a mutiline label on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, label, tail, truncation

How to let a label show multi-line strings?

e.g. The given string is @"HelloA\nHelloB\nHelloC\n".

How to show it like:

@"HelloA"

@"HelloB"

@"HelloC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find some properties to customize UILabel:

```
label.numberOfLines = 3;
label.adjustsFontSizetoFitWidth = YES;
label.minimumFontSize = 8.0f;
```

And '\n' can be used as tail truncation mark.